# Get records based on conditions on a set of related records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two classes

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :camp
  has_many :vaccinations
end

class Vaccination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

Each vaccination has members called vaccine_id. A 'complete' vaccination consists of a set of (say) 6 different vaccines, with `:name`s = {A,B,C,D,E,F}.

Patients receive many vaccinations, and I want a report of all the patients who received 'complete' vaccinations. Is there a SQL or ActiveRecord query I can use to get this list of patients?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
# in patient.rb
scope :with_completed_vaccinations, ->(number) {
  joins(:vaccinations).group('patients.id').
    having('COUNT(vaccinations.name) >= ?', number)
}
```

With this `scope` you are able to write queries like:

```
Patient.with_completed_vaccinations(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to get all patients who have received complete at least one complete vaccination:

```
Patient.select { |pat| pat.vaccinations.any? { |vac| vac.complete? } }
```

And for patients where all vaccinations are complete, just switch the .any? with a .all?

And you could wrap this in a scope, for example by putting this method in your patient.rb

```
def self.with_complete_vaccinations
  select { |pat| pat.vaccinations.any? { |vac| vac.complete? } }
end
```

This all assumes you have a complete? method defined for your vaccination model.

Comment: This is a very inefficient, because it first loads every patients into memory and then run one query for every patient against the database to load that patient's vaccinatons...